# Let $\alpha, \beta :M \to M$ be two nonzero maps of finitely generated modules. Show that $\sigma = \alpha + \beta$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a ring, $m \subseteq J(A)$ a nonzero ideal, where $J(A)$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$. Let $\alpha, \beta :M \to M$ be two nonzero maps of finitely generated modules. Assume $\alpha$ is surjective and $\beta(M) \subseteq mM$. Now define $\sigma = \alpha + \beta$. Show that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism.

Now I was thinking initially that surjectivity would be easy but it was not the case as for any $n \in N$ $m_1n\in mN$ then $\exists m_1'$ s.t $\beta(m_1')=m_1n$ and we can have $m_2$ s.t $\alpha(m_2)=n-m_1n$

Now there is no gurantee that this $m_1' , m_2$ would be same.

Then I recall that I have studied **Cayley-Hamilton Theorem** which states:
"$M$ is a finitely generated (f.g) $A$-module, $I \subseteq A$ an ideal. $\phi : M \to M$ endomorphism of $M$ s.t. $\phi(M) \subseteq IM$. Then $\phi$ satisfies $\phi^n + a_1 \phi^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$ where $a_i \in I$"

and from that using the proof of Nakayama lemma we proved that

"If $M$ is f.g. $A$-module, $\phi : M \to M$ epimorphism then $\phi$ one-one, i.e. isomorphism."

Now can I prove that $\beta $ is also an isomorphism or $\alpha + \beta$ is isomorphism so that my purpose is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $(\alpha+\beta)u\equiv\alpha u\pmod{mM}$ then $\alpha+\beta$ induces
a surjection from $M/mM$ to $M/mM$. Thus $(\alpha+\beta)(M)+mM=M$.
So $(\alpha+\beta)(M)+J(A)M=M$ and Nakayama gives $(\alpha+\beta)(M)=M$. So $\alpha+\beta$ is surjective, etc.